# jquery to use hidden fields from coldfusion page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have the below on a coldfusion page. I am passing item ID as a hidden field so it can be used later.

```
<cfloop query="the_item_list">
    <a href="index.cfm?item_id=#item_id#">#the_item_list.item_title#</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="pdf_filename" value="#replace(the_item_list.item_title,' ','_','ALL')#">
</cfloop>
```

Below is the jquery I am using to try and rename a pdf file that is being created based on the item_title. In this case I have 2 item titles, I want the file name to look like report_title_1_title_2.pdf. With the below I am only getting the first title on the file name. How do I get both of the title on there.

```
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
        var hiddenValue = $(this).val(); 
        //alert(hiddenValue); 

        if(hiddenValue != undefined){
        filename = 'report_'+hiddenValue+'.pdf';
        }else{
            filename = 'report.pdf';
        }
    });
    doc.save(filename);
```

Comment: The `id` of a DOM element should be unique, so append the file id to it: `id="pdf_filename_#item_id#"`.  Also, a class selector would be faster than looking up hidden inputs. You may also end up with hidden inputs that are not related to this functionality in the future, so it would be better to add an arbitrary class name to each element related to the pdf file names: `class="pdfFilename"`. You code would then start `$('.pdfFilename').each()`.

Comment: Kind of hard to determine the intent here.  If the user selects an anchor tag, the value of the input is not passed to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

doc.save(filename) is outside the .each() function, so it is only going to run once with a single filename. Your code should be pulling both filenames, see this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3pcv55qm/2/

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var hiddenValue = "";
    $('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
      var hiddenValue += $(this).val() + "_";

  });
 //console.log( hiddenValue );
 $( "body" ).append( "<h3>" + hiddenValue + "</h3>" );
});
```

Comment: I want a way to concatenate the two file name that are being returned in hiddenValue, and then do the doc.save(filename); not do the save as 2 different file names as you are suggesting

Comment: Check my edited response. You need to append the values inside the loop.